# Hide specific elements in bootstrap sidebar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, hide, show, sidebar

I have the following code

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="navhead">My Title</li>
                <li> <a href="#intro" class="sidebar">Introduction</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#firstCategory" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle sidebar">First Category</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="firstCategory">
                    <li><a href="#firstCategory2" class="sidebar">Intro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#firstItem" class="sidebar internal">First Item</a></li>
...
            <a id="firstItem"></a>
            <div id="firstItemDiv" class="internal">
...
```

I used to hide the internal class in my **$(document).ready(function ()** with **$('.internal').hide();** if a URL parameter was specified.  However, this caused DOM/Page flicker, so I added **.internal {display: none}** to my .css file and now call **$('.internal').show();** in my **ready** when the parameter is specified.

In other words, **Intro** always shows, but **First Item** should only show when the URL parameter is specified.

This works great for my **firstItemDiv**, but my sidebar **internal** li element (**First Item**) still shows.  How can I get it not to show by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(true confessions: I was able to peek at the actual page with the issue)

The issue here was that there was a more "specific" rule that was overriding the "internal" class rule.
There was a rule with "id" specificity:

```
#sidebar ul li a {
    display: block;
}
```

and another with class specificity:

```
.internal {
    display: none;
}
```

changing the second one to:

```
#sidebar .internal, .internal {
    display: none;
}
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach `css` also.  If I understand correctly you change `.internal` ( hiding or showing ) and it works for `id='firstItemDiv'` and doesnt work for `class="sidebar internal"` because it uses some javascript propably...

Try to use

`$(".internal').css("display" , "none!important")` instead of `$(".internal").hide()` and
 `$(".internal').css("display" , "block!important")` instead of `show()`.